# Getting pivot table information within controller Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5.4, relationships

my tables:
[image]

I have the following controller:

```html
public function index($id){
  $user = User::find($id)->group()->id;
  $group = Group::with('files.urls')->findOrFail($user);
  $data ['group'] = $group;
  return view('upload.files', $data);
 }
```

Basically in $id - i have id of the user. $user variable should get group_id of that user and use that id in findOrFail function to retrieve group information.

Relationships:

```html
class Group extends Model
{
 public function course(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');
 }
 public function user(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
 }
 public function files(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\File'); 
 }
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'phone'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function group(){
     $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your eloquent relationships?

Comment: @georgeos, edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationships are ok.

I think your logic is not well because it's considering just one group for the user, but a user could have many groups.

You should consider retrieve all groups first then perform the rest of the logic.

```
$groups = App\User::find(1)->group()->get()->toArray();
$groups = array_column($groups, 'group');
$files = App\Files::select('urls')->whereIn('group_id', $groups);
```

**Edit.**

Your group relationship in the User model doesn't have a return.

Comment: What are you getting from the first line? instead of 1 should be $id.

Comment: I get, call to function get() on null.

Comment: Big mistake... you're missing return in the group relationship.